# Draw Dashed line by using draw method in cocos2d iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, draw

I am working on to create a dashed line by using draw method with no.of points in touch moved direction. I create a number of points on the screen with touch moved points by using draw method. but i want draw a dashed line with touch moved direction like in flight control app and whenever touch end, the dashed line is disappear/fadeout and a thin smooth line is created with the same points..

How is it possible....

please explain this one....

Answer (score 0):

You can have a play with CCMotionStreak, not sure if you can get it dotted, but its east to draw good lines with fade etc.